Select the point of a curve closer to a vector and move it
I have these 3 curve lines:

Generated by this simple node setup:

Now I need to select only the vertex of the curves which is closer to a vector with the values of (5, 0, 3), so in this scenario the endpoint of the second curve should be selected. Then i need to move this vertex of, say, 2 units on the X axis.
I've tried to do this simple operation with the following node setup, but nothing happens:


you could try this node setup:


Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

you are welcome
